# Dart Angular SlowComponentLoader

Tags: angular, exception, dart

What does this exception mean and how to fix it?

> dart_sdk.js:99879 EXCEPTION: Unsupported operation: You are using
>   runApp or runAppAsync, which does not support loading a component with
>   SlowComponentLoader. Please migrate this code to use ComponentLoader
>   instead.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/221c5a986e129d0737a17425d3b4aeb7a757de98/doc/faq/component-loading.md https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/48a0c9a0bf3d8b10bb64ebcdfcbce996cbd4341e/doc/migrating-to-v5.md#remove-usage-of-dynamiccomponentloader

Answer (score 0):

This says you are using the new way to initialize the Angular app, but missed some other migration steps.

Instead of `SlowComponentLoader` you should migrate to `ComponentLoader`

- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/221c5a986e129d0737a17425d3b4aeb7a757de98/doc/faq/component-loading.md
- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/48a0c9a0bf3d8b10bb64ebcdfcbce996cbd4341e/doc/migrating-to-v5.md#remove-usage-of-dynamiccomponentloader
- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/1f89e51b413dd9e6bee74890a73bc32d04e3c46d/angular/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-2